# c++ error code Format '%c' expects argument of type 'int'

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

I am pretty new to C++ and making a program that takes a command line argument and counts how many arguments there are then prints the amount of characters and how many of them are alphabetical. I am getting this error code 
Format '%c' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'char*'

(my code)

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<cctype>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cstring>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /*
    irrelevant 
    printf 
    statements
    */

    for(pos=0; pos < maxCharLen; pos++){
        int count;

        char totalLen = strlen(argv[pos]);
        char totalAlpha (isalpha(argv[pos][pos]);

        printf("Argument %d is", count);
        printf("%c and %c is it's length.\n", argv[pos], totalLen);
        printf("%c are alphabetic characters\n", totalAlpha);
        count ++
    count++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are a number of typos in this code. `0` instead of `)`, `is alpha` (there should not be a space), and missing `}` brackets. Is this the exact code you tried to compile?

Comment: no just what i thought was essential

Comment: The error code tells you what's wrong.  Why don't you change totalLength to type int, like it asks?

Comment: It's hard to debug your code if you are not posting exactly what you tried to compile. It would help if you took a look here [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: made changes @smead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`argv` is array of `char*` so `argv[pos]` returns `char*` so you should use `%s`. After all correct format is:

```
printf("%s and %c is it's length.\n", argv[pos], totalLen);
```